# iteration from java to objective c

Tags: java, objective-c, iteration

I need to transfer some java code into objective-c. Following code:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> filterIDs11 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> filterIDs29 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer id : ((type == FilterType.BITS_11)
                ? filterIDs11
                : filterIDs29))
        { //some code}
```

I know how iterators works, but the way I would implement the same in objective-c is pretty expensive. Maybe I miss or don't know something. As array list I take is `NSMutableArray` filled with `NSNumber`. To iterate with this numbers I would need something like: `int i in (yes or no) ? [filterIDs11 intValue]` ..... but this doesn't work. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write

```
for (NSNumber* number in (type == FilterType_Bits11 ? filterIDs11 : filterIDs29))
{
    ...
}
```

You can't use id as a variable name because id is a reserved word in Objective-C (pointer to any Objective-C object).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew that should be so easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be so cute!

```
ArrayList<Integer> filter;

if (type == FilterType.BITS_11) {
    filter = filterIDs11;
}
else {
    filter = filterIDs29;
}
for (Integer id : filter) {
    ....
```

Easy to understand and easily translated to Objective-C.

Sigh!  Since some people need it spelled out:

```
NSArray filter;

if (type == FilterType_BITS_11) {
    filter = filterIDs11;
}
else {
    filter = filterIDs29;
}
for (NSNumber id in filter) {
    ....
```

Of course, one could maintain the original contorted expression:

```
for (NSNumber id in ((type == FilterType_BITS_11)
            ? filterIDs11
            : filterIDs29))
```

But why?

Comment: This is not Objective C

Comment: @samir - No, but translating to Objective-C is trivial.